# Swift iOS - setContentHuggingPriority is prioritizing the wrong label

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uilabel

I have a cell with 4 labels:

2 separate static labels and 2 separate dynamic labels. The text in the 2 static labels always says *Receipt #* and the other says *Receipt Date*.

The way I set it up is the static labels both have leading anchors pinned to the cell's contentView's leadingAnchor. They both have `setContentHuggingPriority` set to `High` and `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` set to `Low`. Their bottomAnchors are attached to each of their matching dynamic label's `lastBaseLineAnchor`

The dynamic labels both have their trailing Anchors pinned to the contentView's trailingAnchor.

The receiptNumberLabel's leadingAnchor is pinned to the the receiptDateLabel's leadingAnchor.

The receiptDateLabel's leadingAnchor is pinned 10 points away from the staticReceiptDateLabel. This label is the label that should be flexible but it's not. Since the receiptNumberLabels' leadingAnchor follows this it's misaligned also.

[image]

As you can see the staticReceiptDateLabel is longer but it should be shorter and the receiptDateLabel should be longer. I've tried different combinations for the values for `setContentHuggingPriority` and `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` but no matter what I keep getting these results, how can I fix this?

```
contentView.addSubview(receiptNumberLabel) // dynamic
contentView.addSubview(staticReceiptNumberLabel)
contentView.addSubview(receiptDateLabel) // dynamic
contentView.addSubview(staticReceiptDateLabel)

receiptNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
receiptNumberLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

staticReceiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
staticReceiptNumberLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptNumberLabel.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
staticReceiptNumberLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
staticReceiptNumberLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

receiptDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptNumberLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
receiptDateLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

staticReceiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
staticReceiptDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
staticReceiptDateLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
staticReceiptDateLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments @bsod suggested not to use the hugging/compression at all. I initially didn't use them and the same problem occurred, I switched to them as a last resort. Here is the code without the hugging/compression.

```
receiptNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

staticReceiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
staticReceiptNumberLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptNumberLabel.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true

receiptDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptNumberLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

staticReceiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
staticReceiptDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: The bounds of "Receipt #:" and "Receipt Date:" are never going to change so why even work with the hugging/compression API here? Hugging and compression is suited for labels competing for the same space as they shrink and expand but in this example, only one label (the value label) shrinks and expands. Therefore, why not simply pin the leading anchors of each value label to the trailing of the title label (trailing to the cell's trailing) and either truncate them if they grow too large or simply spill over to a second line?

Comment: I did do that at first and when it happened I was like "huh". That's when I decided to use the hugging/compression. It's a strange problem. I'm not worried about them growing to long because I made it so the cell expands (that works fine).

Comment: Wouldn't you rather keep the title labels fixed and let the value labels expand to however many lines they need?

Comment: That's exactly what did. The value labels expand with no problem. There are more labels in the cell and one of them is a descriptionLabel and it expands many lines. Initially I didn;t use the hugging/compression at all. I had only used the leading and lastBaseLine anchors for the static labels

Comment: My point is that there is no need for the hugging/compression API here.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree with you 100% but what I'm saying is I initially didn't use hugging/compression at all on any of the labels and the same problem occurred. The hugging/compression was a last resort

Comment: I updated the answer with the original code not using the hugging/compression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the hugging/compression API and use this as a starting point. Start with the upper-left label and work your way down left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Notice that the static date label's top anchor is pinned to the bottom of the receipt number's value label in case it has more than one line.

```
staticReceiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
staticReceiptNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

receiptNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptNumberLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptNumberLabel.trailing, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptNumberLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

staticReceiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptNumberLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
staticReceiptDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiptNumberLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

receiptDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptDateLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticReceiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
receiptDateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

You also likely need to explicitly set the title labels' `numberOfLines` to 1 otherwise UIKit may truncate the value label even if its `numberOfLines` is 0.

If, for whatever reason, you don't even want the static labels to expand in size, perhaps because you give them a background color, then you can introduce the hugging/compression API. If so, the static labels would be:

```
theStaticLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
theStaticLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

and the dynamic labels would be:

```
theDynamicLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
theDynamicLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it in a few. The way I had it setup was the value labels were driving the expansion (vertically if they grew) and they would push each other down. I didn’t think making it from left to right made a difference but let’s see. Hopefully that resolves the issue. Thanks, I let you know what happens in about 1/2 hr

Comment: You work from left-to-right, top-to-bottom because each new label relies on the position of the label either to the left of it or above it.

Comment: I normally do but in this situation because of the values being dynamic I tried it differently. Regardless of l-r or r-l shouldn’t the cell compute the anchors based on the commands given to it? It sounds like your saying l-r would still take priority over r-l only if it was declared first

Comment: You could rearrange the order, sure, the autolayout API would apply them no differently, but wouldn't that just be confusing?

Comment: lol that's exactly what's happening here. It's definitely an eye sore but it still should've worked. I dunno. But I think your suggestion should fix it

Comment: I edited it to include hugging and compression should you ultimately want it.